# Assign string array to two dimensional string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm a little bit confused. I try to assign a string array to a two dimensional string array. But get "Wrong number of indices" error.
I understand the error, but should it not be possible to assign an array to the second dimension array field?

As `sortedString` has `x` number of fields with each an string array, should it not be possible to assign an string array to just a indexed field? (as the `s.Split(';')` already creates an array)

```
string[,] sortedString = new string[count,columns];
sortedString[counter] = s.Split(';');
```

Comment: You could use a jagged array: `string[][] sortedString = new string[count][];`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a multidimensional array with a jagged array. `sortedString` is a 2-dimensional array of type `string`, so you must always provide the correct number of indices - in this case, 2. You can't say `sortedString[x]`, you can only say `sortedString[x, y]`.

You're probably thinking of a jagged array - i.e., a single-dimensional array, where each element is itself a (usually single-dimensional) array. Declare `sortedString` like this:

```
string[][] sortedString = new string[count][];
```

This will allow each "inner" array to be of a different length (depending on how many `;` there are in each `s`), which might not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I come from Java, and I'm not sure if I ever used multidimensional arrays correctly. 
string[][] sortedString = new string[count][]; this worked perfectly. Thanks! 
Have to read more about that, sounds interessting.

Answer (score 0):

C# has two kinds of 2D arrays. If you need access to one dimension at a time as it's own array, you must use the "jagged" variety, like this:

```
string[][] sortedString = new string[count][];
for(int i = 0; i<sortedString.Length;i++)
    sortedString[i] = new string[columns];
```

Or, even better:

```
var sortedString = new List<string[]>;
```

Comment: Thank you that helped. I come from Java, and I'm not sure if I ever used multidimensional arrays correctly. string[][] sortedString = new string[count][]; this worked perfectly. Thanks! Have to read more about that, sounds interessting.